# 500 error as response while executing post API

Tags: python, python-2.7, proxy, python-requests, http-status-code-500

Data members of the dictionary having None values are being assigned values from external function in the actual code.

While sending request to the above mentioned URL, getting 500 error code as reponse.

```
    os.environ['http_proxy'] = "http://127.0.0.1:8888"
    os.environ['https_proxy'] = "http://127.0.0.1:8888"
    headers = {
        'Content-Length': "1000",
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1; en-us; A5 Build/LMY47I) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750 Mobile Safari/537.36",
        'Host': 't.appsflyer.com',
        'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip'
        }
    params = {
        'buildnumber':"3.7",
        'app_id' : 'kr.co.company.hwahae'
        }
    data = {
        'device': None,
        'firstLaunchDate': "2018-05-11_1726+0530",
        'installDate': "2018-05-11_1652+0530",
        'sdk': None,
        'referrer': "utm_source=(not%20set)&utm_medium=(not%20set)",
        'carrier': None,
        'deviceFingerPrintId': "ffffffff-c43e-0f72-0000-0000554b5f2f",
        'date1': "2018-05-11_1652+0530",
        'af_preinstalled': "false",
        'advertiserIdEnabled': "true",
        'iaecounter': "0",
        'lang_code': "en",
        'appsflyerKey': "vyrpAMjHsud67YVPR5ZK4S",
        'installer_package': "com.android.vending",
        'app_version_name': "3.11.2",
        'lang': "English",
        'timepassedsincelastlaunch': "23",
        'dkh': "vyrpAMjH",
        'advertiserId': "3487698f-5e5b-447a-b79f-77bebd0be996",
        'isGaidWithGps': "true",
        'deviceType': None,
        'af_v': None,
        'app_version_code': "120",
        'af_events_api': "1",
        'platformextension': "android_native",
        'network': None,
        'operator': "",
        'country': None,
        'date2': "2018-05-11_1652+0530",
        'brand': None,
        'af_timestamp': "1526039807811",
        'uid': "1526037747370-5406320771079142546",
        'isFirstCall': "false",
        'counter': "2",
        'model': None,
        'product': None
        }
    url = 'https://t.appsflyer.com/api/v4/androidevent'
    requests.post(url, data = params, headers = headers, proxies = os.environ)
```

I am a newbie in python, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'd need to check the server logs to know the real reason behind the error 500. This could be anything

Comment: could it be you proxy URL that trigger these 500 errors ? otherwise check your API provider